# Hash table implementation in python

Tags: python, hash

I want to implement hash table in python. 
Since the hashing basic idea is to store the value in the index i where i = hash_function(key), I need to be able to index a list/array to store the value. But since the size of lists in python expands with .append(), the hashList[i] statement will cause "List assignment index out of range".

Is there a twist to use lists with fixed size and indexing it normally? or shall I use a ctype array ?

Here's how the code might look like:

```
class Hash():
    length = 1000
    array = [] 

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        sum = 0  
        if key != None: 
            for letter in key: 
                sum = sum + ord(letter)
        self.array[sum % self.length] = self.length
```

Comment: I assume this is "academic" -- python already has a wonderful builtin hash table called a `dict`

Comment: Create a list with `listSize` many `None`s to begin with. Then you can consider an index with `None` to be an empty hash bucket

Comment: @mgilson: depending on the use case, OP might also consider using `set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class HashTable():

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 1000
        self.table = [None] * self.size

    def add(self, item):
        hashcode = self.hash(item)
        if hashcode >= self.size:
            # Resize the table.
            self.size *= 2
            # etc.
        else:
            self.table[hashcode] = item

    def hash(self, item):
        # Your implementation of a hash function.
```

Comment: This hash table implementation is unable to handle collisions.

Comment: does "[None] * self.size" consume O(size) time?

Comment: @user1203631 But there's still plenty of room in the `add` function. :)

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to construct the hash with O(1) like in C++?

Comment: @user1203631 I don't understand algorithmic complexity all that well - but I would think Python would construct the `[None] * self.size` list all at once? It's probably not a bunch of `appends` strung together.

Comment: @sdasdadas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254356/python-list-creation-by-multiplication-operator-time-complexity

Comment: @user1203631 Ah, thank you. I'm afraid I don't know of a way without using some sort of container within Python. As stated, the best choice is a `dict` if this is for anything other than your own research.

Comment: @user1203631 **Constructing** a hash is not O(1) in C++, nor anywhere else. It's the lookup (and insertion) that is O(1), assuming a well-chosen hash function.

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks, but isn't array declaration is O(1)? 
what else would you need in the construction of empty hash? the insertion will wait till the user insert

Comment: @user1203631 Creating a POD array is O(1), but initializing it is O(n), and you need to initialize the array to use it in a hash table. Realistic hash tables resolve this by starting out with tiny capacity and resizing exponentially on insertion. This has nothing to do with the difference between C++ and Python, but with the difference between a good algorithm and a bad one.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a twist to use lists with fixed size and indexing it normally?

Yes, initialize your array
i.e.

```
for i in range(0,1000):
    array.append(None)
```

Then you can go ahead and set your values in any index between 0-9999

-

shall I use a ctype array ?

```
Python lists are arrays
```

Comment: If you're going to predefine your array, `[None] * 1000` should be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

As @mgilson noted, the dict is the built-in hash-table for python, so this answer assumes you're doing this for academic reasons only.

Here's one way to create a fixed size list in python filled with None values:

```
import itertools

hashSize = 100
myHashList = list(itertools.repeat(None, hashSize))
```

See [Wikipedia: Hash Table - Dynamic resizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Dynamic_resizing) for more info about what to do when you run out of space in the hash table.