# Python: List creation by multiplication operator time complexity

Tags: python, big-o

Python
What's the time complexity of using

```
a = [1]*n
```

vs.

```
for i in range(n): 
    a.append(1)
```

Are both O(n) or does the first O(1)?

Comment: is `n` an integer ? If it is you can't iterate over an integer

Comment: I've forget range, thanks

Comment: Both are O(n), but the first is likely to execute faster.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know why it's faster?

Comment: I agree with @mgilson. The for loop is going to take more time since you have to set up the range function. Just giving the fact that you have to call another function should make it a bit slower.

Comment: @user1203631 -- The first constructs the list in C code whereas the second will construct it in python code.  The difference is likely not going to matter much though unless you have it in a really tight loop.

Comment: Two things which come in handy for these questions: the [time complexity page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) and the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: Why don't we experiment it? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uSnhB7d42xOIfECmlQTNQbX_Tu0h2EdO?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former is O(n), due to the use of [`PyList_New()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html#PyList_New) with a known size. The latter is slightly worse than O(n), due to the need to [resize the list](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.6/file/ba31940588b6/Objects/listobject.c#l25) after several appends.

Comment: The latter *is* `O(n)`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: It is *very close* to O(n). In theory it is O(n), but several practical issues prevent it from actually being O(n).

Comment: What practical issues? Generally if you allow for practical issues everything is `O(1)` because `n` is bounded above by a constant due to implementation or hardware limits ;-) But to quantify "very close", does there exist epsilon > 0 such that it's `Omega(n^(1 + epsilon))`?