# What is the big O time of this function (Plus One question from LeetCode)

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am just trying to practice reasoning through big O of my leetcode solutions.

This is my solution to a problem called "[Plus One](https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/559/)". I am simply wondering what the Big O time is here. My thoughts and notes are accompanied in the code

```py
class Solution:
    def plusOne(self, digits: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        def incrementer(digits,place):
            if (digits[-place] != 9):              # My base case
                digits[-place] = digits[-place] + 1
                return digits
            else:
                try:
                    next = digits[-place-1]
                except IndexError:
                    digits = [0]*(place+1) # This takes O(n) time?
                    digits[0] = 1
                    return digits
                digits[-place] = 0
                # Recursive case
                return incrementer(digits,place+1) # Recursive Case # O(n)?

        return incrementer(digits,1)
```

I believe this will result in O(n^2) at worse because that would mean it would have gone through the whole array, and then created a new array of size n + 1, filled with 0s. Am I correct in this thinking? This would occur for a number like 9999999, where all of the 9's end up getting flipped and then the new array is created for the new place.

Comment: You shouldn't use `next` like that. `next` is a function in python that is used when calling the next value in a generator.

Comment: More importantly, there's little reason to use recursion here rather than a loop. It will incur  a lot more overhead, and limit the length of lists you can handle without hitting the stack-size limit.

Comment: Back in the old days, we would have closed this as "too localized". A good knowledge base entry -- and thus, a good Stack Overflow question -- is likely to be helpful to other people, not just the person first asking the question. It's unlikely that the next person to ask "what is the big-O time of this function?" will have the exact same function, or -- even if they do! -- that they'll be able to locate this particular question.

Comment: Even if you have a name for the algorithm you're implementing, putting the name of that algorithm into the question title makes it easier for people with the same question to find your question, and thereby makes it more likely to be valuable/useful as a part of our site.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated the title as you recommended :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not quite correct, but close; in Python, [array creation is O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254356/python-list-creation-by-multiplication-operator-time-complexity), and to reach that line in worst case, you need to traverse the entire list which is also O(n). So you have O(n + n) which is O(2n) (but we discard multipliers, so we would classify this as O(n) again).

But like chepner said, iteration would be better here. And to swing off of Ariel A, instead of the `try except` block to check if `place + 1` is out of index bounds, you could use

`if place + 1 >= len(digits)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This clears it up for me and makes sense. I can see how it is n+n because the copy only happens once at the end, not on every iteration.

Comment: @Emma I believe its O(1) is it not? Because It is changing the element at that index, which is a constant operation.

Answer (score 0):

I made your code less complicated as you can see there is only one while loop which means O(n) time complexity:

```
class Solution:
    def plusOne(self, digits: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        n = len(digits) - 1
        while n >= 0:
            if digits[n] != 9:
                digits[n] += 1
                return digits
            else:
                digits[n] = 0
                n -= 1
        return [1] + digits
```