# Time Complexity of List creation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

If you initialize a list in python like this:

EDIT: THIS IS PSEDUOCODE

```
l = list([1,2,3,4....N])
```

or

```
l = list(range(N))
```

or

```
l = list("string of len N")
```

Would the time complexity of these operations be O(N)? Because, you would need to iterate through all of the items up to N and append it to the list. Append is O(1). Therefore, it is N*O(1) = O(N).

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Python: List creation by multiplication operator time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20254356/4518341)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Those threads suggest it is O(N), which is what I speculate. But they don't explain why. Can anyone find concrete proof why creating a list of size N will be O(N) in python?

Comment: The proof is what you wrote in your question: `append` is O(1) and you do it n times. Technically `append` is only O(1) amortised time, but that's good enough for the proof to work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the list particularly was implemented. For example, if you already have a list that you pass as an argument, the upper bound for creating a copy or appending a list at the end of it might be `O(1)`. But, for the general case where you append `n` elements to a list, assuming you have a pointer at the end of the list and there is no shifting of values to the left or to the right, then that indeed would be `O(n)`. However, if you want to insert `n` elements at an arbitrary position in the list, which would require shifting, that again depends on what implementation you are dealing with, but it will generally be `O(n^2)` since either elements need to be shifted (in an array based list) or the list has to be traversed to find the position where you want to insert (like in a linked list).