# Is the [0]*n runs in O(n) or O(1) in Python

Tags: python, list, big-o

I was in an interveiw and the interviewer asked me: What is the fastest way to create a list of all zeros in Python with length = n. My answer was:

```
    l = [0 for i in range(n)]
```

Which is of order O(n). It was rejected as the interviewer told me the code bellow runs in O(1).

```
    l = [0]*n
```

My question is, how Python manages to create this list in O(1)?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254356/python-list-creation-by-multiplication-operator-time-complexity

Comment: At a guess. It knows how many elements it has to allocate. So if its 1 or its a million it can do them all in one go. You just have to be careful when using this style of initialization with mutable objects. As you get a list of references to the same object and it can go seriously awry.

Comment: `[0] * n` doesn't seem to be `O(1)`. I changed `n` from 10 through 1000000000 in steps of 100 and the creation time varied from nanosecs(n=10) to several secs(n=1000000000)

Comment: I think I see where they're coming from, but I'm not sure if they're right. The list itself is the same size (n elements) either way. `[0 for i in range(n)]` nominally creates n 0s while `[0]*n` creates just one 0. But I'm pretty sure Python interns small `int`s so the immutable 0 is reused in the first case too...

Comment: It has to physically put those `0`s into places in memory, and the more there are, the longer it must take. So it's O(n) either way. The multiplication is probably slightly more efficient, as it allows Python to do a lot of efficient C under the hood, but that doesn't change the fact that it must be O(n). You'd see a larger effect for something like `[Foo()]`, where it makes a difference whether the object reference is simply multiplied, or a new object instantiated each time.

Comment: Good question. I did some naive timings here and it is indeed O(n). `[0]*n` is about one order of magnitude faster than the list comprehension version but still grows with `n`. Your interviewer was wrong (about the time complexity).

Comment: The second one is faster indeed, but it has nothing to do with asymptotic complexity, that interviewer is a textbook example of Dunning-Kruger effect.